# Creating asp.net application which will open in defined position(bottom of the window) with a fixed size(width and height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

**Hi there,**
I want to create a web application(asp.net preferable) which will run with default browser and the browser will open in the defined position(bottom of the window) with a fixed size(width and height). By the way, the browser will open after clicking on .exe file(I already know how to create .exe to open the website with default browser, but don't know how to open the site in the defined position with a fixed size). Looking for your help.
Kindest regards.

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with `javascript`, `jQuery`, and `twitter-bootstrap` its completely depended on `.net` code.

Comment: take a look at this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx